# Azure Dev Ops Multiple Parallel Tasks on a Single Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run multiple parallel tasks on Azure Dev Ops.

Do I need to have 1 agent per Parallel task? Or can a single agent take on multiple parallel tasks?

Comment: what is the "tasks"? basiccaly each agent does 1 thing, so of you want to a few tasks to run in parallel you need 1 agents per task.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks are executed sequentially in one job (and one job = one agent). So if you have them run in parallel you need to put them in separate jobs (which may not be a solution for you). There is feature request to [enable parallel task](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ability-to-run-tasks-in-parallel/365659) (so please consider upvoting it) - but this is not possible at the moment.